# Как нарисовать рамку с помощью svg не используя clip-path?

Tags: html, css, svg

Подскажите как сделать шестиугольную рамку вокруг картинки, не используя clip-path.
Так как данная технология является новой и не поддерживается на старых версиях браузеров.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А насколько старые версии браузеров вас интересуют?

Comment: _"... как сделать шестиугольную рамку вокруг картинки..."_ Хм... Вижу только пятиугольную.

Answer (score 1):

Если без [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) то можно использовать [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns) для вставки [изображения в svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image)  в уже нарисованный [путь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) для картинки ... смотрим дэмо в сниппете

Соответственно что бы корректно отображалось в старых браузерах то обязательно подключаем все [пространства имён в заголовок SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course) и используем подключение изображений через [xlink:href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href) но его лучше не использовать в SVG второй версии

```css
.svg {
  max-width: 300px
}
```

```html
<div class="svg">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 6.1 6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" viewBox="0 0 6 6" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0">
      <image xlink:href="https://vk.vkfaces.com/845522/v845522328/21ad3/Ob0So4Mk6BQ.jpg" width="6" height="6.3" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="-0.15" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="6.1" height="6" fill="#F9D630" x="0" />

  <g>
    <path d="M6.1,5.5 3,3 6.1,0.5 " fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0.1" />
    <path d="M6.1,4.7 4.2,3 6.1,1.3" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0.05" />
    <path d="M6.1,4 5,3 6.1,2" fill="#000" />
  </g>

  <path d="M0,0 3,0 6,3 3,6 0,6z" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0.1" fill="url(#pattern)" />

</svg>
</div>
```